# Don't show user fields on admin/people/create

Tags: 7, entities, users

Basically I don't want to have fill out all the required fields that I have added to a user when I am adding a user via admin/people/create. In Drupal 6 there was an option to not even show those fields when the admin makes a user. I have looked around for that but have failed to find it in drupal 7. I suppose I could do a hook_form_alter but I was hoping there might be something already made that I can drop in.

I was using content profile in D6 for this and it has become profile2 for D7. Since posting I have found this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1057958) which states that a module needs to be made in order to have that same type of option.

Comment: Well, `hook_form_alter()` is the fastest and most reliable solution. It does not depend on module update/upgrade, and it always works.

Answer (score 1):

On each of the field settings for user fields, there is an option "Display on user registration form.". Just uncheck it.

Comment: Thats no good. It must show for users when they register, but not for when an admin signs up new accounts through the page I referenced.

Comment: You said you recall being able to do this in D6, however nothing I can think of did this, unless you are referring to the field level permissions. If so, these did not make it into the Fields module for D7 and therefore this functionality lies in The Field Permissions module. http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions

Comment: It's part of the content profile module, but it doesn't seem to have made into profile2 which is what content profile became on d7.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a css to hide the fields for the admin. The [css_injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) module would be a handy tool for that and you could restrict the css to "#overlay=user/*/edit".

A hook_form_alter would be a more robust solution.